# how to save controller.index value into a static variable?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class SignUpConvert extends StatefulWidget {

  const SignUpConvert({ Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 @override
_SignUpConvertState createState() => _SignUpConvertState();
}

class _SignUpConvertState extends State<SignUpConvert>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
TabController? tabController;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
print(tabController!.index);


 }




@override
void dispose() {
super.dispose();

}
```

I want to reflect the current index in a static variable

```
    class MyVariable{
    static int indexCount = 0;
         }
```

so that i can use it to navigate from a same button to different pages

the button is;

```
 onSubmit: (_) {
                      if (MyVariable.indexCount == 0) {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (builder) => LogInConvert()));
                      }
                      else if (MyVariable.indexCount == 1) {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (builder) => SignUpConvert()));

                      }
                    },
```

but the controller.index is not saving in MyVariable.indexCount and i'm getting the default value i.e 0.

i am saving index using custom button

```
CustomButton(
index: widget.tabIndex,
route: widget.pageToNavigate,
backgroundColor: Color(0xff416bbd),
borderColor: Color(0xff416bbd),
name: 'Sign Up',
textColor: Colors.white,
),
```

the index value is then assigned to MyVariable.indexCount.

but it is not working!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `getx Storage` to store the static value and read the value and getstorage.read("store");

```
dependencies:
  get_storage: ^2.0.3
```

example:

```
static final _otherBox = () => GetStorage('MyPref');

  final username = ''.val('username');
  final age = 0.val('age');
  final price = 1000.val('price', getBox: _otherBox);

  // or
  final username2 = ReadWriteValue('username', '');
  final age2 = ReadWriteValue('age', 0);
  final price2 = ReadWriteValue('price', '', _otherBox);
```